# Importing an object that is inside of the exported object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I am exporting an object to be imported into other modules. In other modules I dont need the full object but other objects inside of that exported object. How can I drill down to the specific object inside of the exported object?

exported JS:

```
const data = {
    someObject:{//...},
    anotherObject:{//...}
}

export default data;
```

importing into another file:

```
import data from './dataModule'
```

`data` here is that full object from `dataModule` but I want to get only `someObject` inside of the full object. How can I drill down to importing only that object?

`import data.someObject from './dataModule'` does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [object deconstruction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)  which looks something like this:

```
const obj = {
  name: 'Tim',
  location: {
    lat: 123,
    lng: 321
  }
}

const {name} = obj
const {location: {lat,lng}} = obj
```

And if we want to get it from import, it looks like this:

```
import {name} from './fileWithObj'
```

with an export of so:

```
const obj = {
      name: 'Tim',
      location: {
        lat: 123,
        lng: 321
      }
    }
export default obj
```

Comment: Sorry for probably a redundant question here, but how are you exporting const {name} = obj to be consumed where you are importing it?

Comment: @Chipe, I added a sample export for you. Let me know if you have any questions.